# Send form to remote server

Tags: html, forms

I want to use the service provided at http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx with a custom form in my own site. I've written the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
    <FORM action="http://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx" method="post">
        <INPUT type="text" name="u" value="http://justinsomnia.org/images/qr-code-justinsomnia.png">
        <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> 
    </FORM>
</body>
</html>
```

When I submit the form, I'd expect to see the results page with a "Decode Succeeded" message. Instead, I see the original remote form I'm trying to duplicate.

Can you spot what's wrong with my custom form?

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Or what is your desired result?

Comment: Have you clicked the "Send" button?

Comment: Got this back: http://zxing.org/w/decode?u=http%3A%2F%2Fjustinsomnia.org%2Fimages%2Fqr-code-justinsomnia.png

Comment: And "Decode Succeeded" is a problem because...?

Comment: When I clicked the "Send" button, it is NOT decoding. That is my problem.

Comment: I you prefer having answers rather than endless comments, I suggest you put some effort into your questions and try to explain what you want to do, what you've tried and how exactly it's failing to accomplish the intended goals. I've edited your question to serve as example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   <html>
   <body>
   <FORM action="http://zxing.org/w/decode" method="get">
   <INPUT type="text" name="u" value="http://justinsomnia.org/images/qr-code-justinsomnia.png">
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> 
    </FORM>
    </body>
    </html>
```

You should use **get** instead of the **post** method.  You are posting to the wrong URL, post to http://zxing.org/w/decode.  I checked it, it's working now.

Comment: Many thanks! It is working for URL/GET method. What if I like to upload a local file to the server using POST method?

Comment: No answer is not accpected click the tick mark below the vote of my answer.Thanks you